# How would Donald Trump benefit from a commuted sentence for Rod Blagojevich?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

Recently, US President Donald Trump suggested that he has considered commuting the sentence of former Illinois Governor Rod Blagojevich. Personally, I'm a bit confused by this suggestion for a few reasons:

1. While the two have had some past interactions (like Blagojevich appearing on The Apprentice) Blagojevich is a Democrat, from a traditionally blue state.
2. Blagojevitch is widely disliked, even in Illinois where his approval rating leading up to his 2006 reelection was [as low as 36%](http://www.surveyusa.com/client/PollReport.aspx?g=eb952d0f-9d58-4c0f-9933-a9da05b7e78e), and dropped to [near zero](http://www.rasmussenreports.com/public_content/politics/favorables/governors_approval_ratings) about two months before he was arrested in 2008.
3. Any leniency on Blagojevich would appear to be in direct conflict with Trump's campaign rhetoric in favor of 'Draining the swamp' or 'Locking her up' with respect to Hillary Clinton. I have to assume it would be difficult to convince the Republican voter base otherwise, and that can't make other Republicans happy in the run up to the mid-term elections.
4. It's not as if Blagojevich could ever help Trump with enforcing policy or state-level politics. Even if Blagojevich could hypothetically win an election (which is doubtful) the Illinois Senate not only removed Blagojevich from office, but banned him from ever holding public office in Illinois again.

Some media outlets, including [this article](https://www.cnn.com/2018/05/31/politics/martha-stewart-rod-blagojevich-trump-pardons/index.html) from CNN, have suggested various reasons that Trump might have sympathy for Blagojevich, or might like the narrative that Blagojevich presented in [his own op-ed piece](https://www.wsj.com/articles/im-in-prison-for-practicing-politics-1527517322) from the Wall Street Journal where he argued that the FBI was undermining the rule of law. Still, even if Trump wanted to commute Blagojevich's sentence for personal reasons, I can't see any scenario where doing so, or even suggesting it, would do anything but harm him and his administration. So... what am I missing?

**How could commuting the sentence of Rod Blagojevich, or even suggesting it, benefit Trump or his administration?**

Comment: I don't think there will be any sources on this less speculative than the CNN article.

Comment: Pardons are a form of clemency.  They are not tools designed to exclusively benefit the executive branch of the US government.  While they can have such an effect, they can be simply what they are on their face -- a way to show mercy to those who are known to be guilty.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I was concerned about this too, but was hoping that somebody more savy than myself might have a good source, or know of a past situation which was similar and could be used for context. Do you have any suggestion for how to alter/improve the question?

Comment: I don't think we've ever had a president use pardons the way Trump has used them.   I'm tempted to put that into a new question but I'm not sure how to word it, or if it would be quantifiable enough to be a question, but I've never seen anyone use Pardons as a way to slap the other side in the face the way Trump has.

Comment: @userLTK - I donno, pardoning rich donors for money seems to be far more of a slap in the face to opposite side.

Comment: Everyone answering seems to have never seen Trump before. Otherwise, the answer would start with 2 words: "*entertainment value*"

Comment: @user4012 Ah, the Mark Rich example.  I regret I've not read up on that as much as I'd like, but I never got the sense that Clinton did that to slap the other side in the face. I think Clinton, perhaps through his wife, knew and liked Mark Rich. Some of Trumps pardons, like D'souza or Joe Arpaio (& firing the Judge on the D'souza case), it seems very much trying to slap the other team down. I never got that vibe from Clinton.  He wasn't trying to say "My side is good your side is bad" with the Rich pardon. He just wanted to pardon him.  Trump seems to be saying precisely we're good you're not.

Comment: @userLTK - just because the other team treats it as a slap in the face, doesn't mean it was the goal. The far more likely motivation is to motivate (pardon the phrase) his own team. (think Obama's pardon of Manning)

Comment: @user4012 what you don't seem to understand is that Clinton's pardon of Mark Rich pissed off a whole lot of democrats.   It's also a lot more complex than you realize.    Bill Clinton was very internationally focused.   Mark Rich had made friends in Israel.    Obama's pardon of Manning is a better example and closer to my point about Trump, but I don't think reasonable republicans were outraged by the Manning pardon.   Faux outrage perhaps.   Many people genuinely are outraged by Arpaio and D'souza.   You're reaching.

Comment: Re #3, not pardoning Blagojevich due to "Drain the Swamp" is one possible narrative. But an alternate narrative that would be very cherised by Trump is "the FBI/deep state is  framing innocent politicians". To those who already give some credence to that, the pardon is coherent, and allows the "reasoning" (for lack of a better word) of "You see, it is not only that Trump is bad, the FBI has framed the *good* Democrats too." Or "Trump is not abusing his pardon power by using it only for Republicans."

Comment: It seems this is primarily opinion-based, as we would need to look into Trump's head to give a good answer.

Comment: @Thern We see a lot about people when they become president.   "Looking into Trump's head" . . . I don't know, but looking at Trump's actions, we can reach some tangible conclusions.   That's a byproduct of him being at the helm of so many decisions that we are privy to.   We really do get to know our presidents and we may not know what they think, but we can recognize what they are likely to do based on past actions.

Comment: I haven't seen much to confirm the theory, but one thing I heard was that many of the recent pardons were related by fact that Mueller and/or Comey were very involved in the investigation of the cases that resulted in criminal prosecution.  In a way, invalidating the two investigator's work.  Again, I'd need to do some digging into more sources to confirm, but I've head speculation to such a motive.

Comment: @Thern I specifically avoided asking something like 'why would trump...' because that would definitely be opinion-based. With this wording I feel the question is more appropriate for SE, but it's certainly not perfect. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TexasRed I don't have a good idea. Maybe it is not the question itself but the answers that seem primarily opinion-based and speculative. They may be correct, it is just that it is nigh impossible to verify if they are.

Comment: @user4012 The difference between Manning and Arpaio is the timing.  The pardons are politically motivated, but Manning had already been imprisoned for for years and the pardon was at the end of Obama's term.  As a political act, it can be seen as building Obama's legacy among his base, while also being merely an act of clemency without endorsing leaking government secrets (decade of prison remember).  Arpaio was pardoned before serving any time for things like contempt of court during Trump's first year.  The pardon was very much a political statement endorsing the laws Arpaio broke.

Comment: @Teleka - your comment also points out the difference. Manning got disproportionately light sentence for an extremely heavy crime (whatever he was convicted of technically, he committed treason, in spirit - at least in the view of many). Arpaio may have been put to jail, but for a made-up "crime" of "contempt of court" - and in the eyes of people of his political persuasion, it was he who was upholding the law, trying to stop illegal criminal aliens that Federal government refused to stop. In other words, he was doing the job that Obama swore to do.

Comment: @user4012 Manning did not commit "treason", the term treason is very tightly restricted by the constitution.  It's actually very hard to commit treason under US law.  It can be argued (though I don't subscribe to this view) that even general Flynn, who took money from Turkey to screw over the Kurds and help out ISIS didn't commit treason.  Also, contempt of court is a very real thing, as is violating the fifth amendment rights of US citizens.  TFW I see a "libertarian" let the mask slip and endorse extrajudicial police action. Keep it up champ.

Comment: @Teleka - (1) I very carefully stated that it was treason in spirit, not law. (2) No, Flynn didn't commit treason in any way, even if what you say is correct - because he screwed Kurds and not US - and this is coming from someone 100% anti-Turkey and 100% pro-Kurd. (3) Libertarianism very explicitly recognizes that non-aggression principle does not apply to people who are aggressors (in this case, violated the law). You must be confusing libertarians with early Christians or Quakers.

Comment: @user4012 Flynn's actions aided ISIS in a direct way, the "enemy" party in question is ISIS, not Turkey.  If leaks of secret government documents are always "treason in spirit", then there are dozens of traitors in the White House and Congress right now (not even targeting the current administration or congress, pick any of the past half century).  Things like the pentagon papers would be "treason" by your definition.  And I guess Libertarians are now totally cool with cops ignoring court orders on not randomly detaining and locking up brown people, good to know.

Answer (score 9):

> I can't see any scenario where doing so, or even suggesting it, would do anything but harm him and his administration. So... what am I missing?

Doing so may harm his administration in the court of public opinion, but it sends a very different message to people related to Trump that have problems being resolved in actual courts right now.

For example, the [pardon of Scooter Libby](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/04/13/politics/donald-trump-pardons-scooter-libby/index.html) sends a very clear message that "loyalty" in the form of perjury committed in defense of the administration can be rewarded.  This is very relevant to people like Cohn, Roger Stone, Carter Page, Manafort, Gates, Flynn, and others who are being asked very hard questions about things they know and have done.

A pardon of Blagojevich would go even beyond that because it would reward "loyalty" even further.  Many of Trump's associates relating to his campaign have committed white collar crimes that were directly quid pro quo like Blagojevich.  Off of the top of my head I know that Flynn, Manafort, and Cohn definitely fall into this group with their crimes being completely unrelated to the Trump campaign (note that this does not preclude them knowing or participating in crimes related to the campaign).

Talks of pardon that involve crimes related to associates of Trump is a way to communicate to those associates that "loyalty" will be rewarded and serves as a way to encourage their silence.

The effectiveness of this may be mitigated by the fact that Trump is surrounded by habitual criminals who committed crimes that aren't exclusively under federal jurisdiction so pardons only go so far.

The effect on public opinion is also unclear since such a pardon is consistent Trump's narrative of persecution and the message sent to his associates is much louder and clearer than to the general public.

Comment: This only makes sense if Blagojevich has shown loyalty to Trump though. Has he done that? (Did he even have the opportunity to do so?)

Comment: @tim Neither has Libby, yet he still got his perjury pardoned.  Trump can pardon someone like Flynn right now, who he has repeatedly claimed has been treated "unfairly".  The political consequences of that is obviously much greater than for pardoning people who no longer matter like Libby or Blagojevich.  The point is that the crimes are direct reflections of things his associates are currently facing, it's a way to send them a message without having to deal with (more) accusations of obstruction of justice, and providing more ammunition for political opponents.

Comment: @tim The point is not whether they themselves were are loyal to Trump.  The point is to allow Trump to demonstrate his ability to undermine the law to those around him, in order to get those people to maintain their loyalty in the face of criminal investigation.

Answer (score 3):

There's two reasons that I can see why Trump would pardon/discuss pardoning Blagojevich.

Reason One:

**Friendship/Relationship.**

If Trump likes him and/or has some connection to him, friend of a friend.   Pardoning a friend of a friend is easy enough to understand.

They met on celebrity apprentice but Trump says that beyond that, they don't really know each other and I think that's a fair statement.   Both men were busy and lived in different parts of the country and there would have been little reason for them to maintain a relationship after the show.   Trump, for example, seems to have made very relatively friends prior to his inserting himself into the political arena.    There was Michael Cohen who's been a lawyer and business partner, but all his "friends" appear to be either business related or family.   There's no reason to expect that he and Rod would have been close.  Trump runs a family business.

People who work for law firms or big companies or wall street tend to work as part of a team and they know a lot of people.  (I worked on Wall Street and I saw that as part of my Father's law firm.  Lawyers have clients for example).  Those kind of careers require meeting lots of people.  Trump's business was more insular.  There would have been little reason for him to have an extended relationship with Blagojevich even after they spent time doing a show together briefly.   I tend towards believing Trump when he says that they met, but didn't maintain a relationship after doing the show together.

Reason two (and I think this is the more likely explanation).

**Overzealous prosecutors and distraction.**

Blagojevich reached out to Trump, so let's get that out of the way and Trump has said he would "consider" a pardon.  He hasn't granted one.  That's a key difference.   If Trump is considering it, he can appear to be weighing the evidence.  He can appear thoughtful.  That's what "considering" implies.

Blagojevich has also been very critical of overzealous prosecution.  He claims (incorrectly) to have been imprisoned for being stupid and [saying things that many other politicians say](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/local/breaking/ct-met-illinois-governor-blagojevich-trump-20180531-story.html).  That's of course, bunk.  Blagojevich did accept payments for state contracts and he didn't just say "this is a gold mine", he tried, more than once, to get something in return".   But given that he's serving 14 years, and because a few other politicians have, occasionally been on the take* (citation needed), Blagojevich is seen by some as an example of overzealous prosecution, even if he's guilty, others [who are just as guilty](https://www.cnn.com/2016/06/27/politics/bob-mcdonnell-supreme-court/index.html) aren't serving time.

By considering Blagojevich's request, Trump touches on a couple things he likes.  He exposes what is to some an example of overzealous prosecution against a politician and he appears thoughtful by considering something.   It's a win for Trump to discuss the unfair treatment of Rod Blagojevich because it puts "unfair treatment" out there.

As to whether it's a win for him to issue the pardon, that's harder to say.  Obviously some will cheer, others will boo, but we should cross that bridge when/if the pardon happens.   For now, Trump gets something by saying he's considering it.

If I was to guess (and I know I shouldn't do that here, but I can't help myself because it's fun to guess what Trump will do).  I think Trump will pardon him, but upon leaving office, not now.  By putting it out now, but pardoning him in 2020 with a bunch of other pardons, then it's not a big surprise.   If he pardons him soon, he opens himself up to both criticism as well as praise.

---

And let me add, while he was clearly guilty, Rod Blagojevich was also a first time offender and no more guilty than Bob Mcdonnell, who got off with being forced out of office and a scolding from the supreme court but no jail time.  Bob was smarter and he said in court that the gifts were given to his wife, but I think it's fair to say that he was equally guilty.

I always thought that the 14 year sentence was too harsh.   I realize that might be unnecessary commentary but since I hammered down the point that Blagojevich was guilty, I wanted to add this.   14 years is a lot.

Comment: if you want an example of someone who's not in jail for corruption but should be, check out New Jersey.

Comment: @user4012  That one works too and I'm sure there are others.  The honest truth is, I'd not remembered that.  McDonnell's "My wife took the gifts" stuck in my mind for some reason.   That's why I remembered him.

Comment: The last 538 podcast discussion of Menendez was... hilarious. Falling all over themselves to try to sound nice to him.

Comment: @user4012 you know that this isn't about Menendez, right?   You can make a question about him if you want.   The fact is, the Supreme court re-imagined the law with the McDonnell rulling, even the conservative NY Post said as much:    https://nypost.com/2017/11/19/supreme-court-bribery-ruling-effects-mistrials-for-menendez-seabrook/   I've not heard the 538 podcast.   You can post a link if you like, but we seem to be getting pretty far off the subject of Trump and pardons.

Answer (score 3):

**Publicity for Trump**

Many of Trumps actions appear like the plot of a reality TV show. He adds more tension and surprise than is necessary in his announcements. Controversial pardons like this one work to keep Trump in the news and increase his ‘ratings’.

**Sending a Message**

Trump may want to send a message to people who are worried that they could be prosecuted as part of the Muller investigation. These people could be tempted to work with Muller in return for immunity. If Trump issues several high profile and controversial pardons then these people could conclude Trump will pardon them also.

Comment: This is a reasonable interpretation of how this could benefit Trump, or anyone in Trump's position, without delving into rank speculation.

Answer (score -1):

This answer relies on a large number of assumptions.  Many of the assumptions I disagree with personally.  Especially (me being from Illinois) the idea that Blago deserves any sort of leniency, compassion, or fresh air.

Doing the right thing is not about how it benefits you.  Sometimes doing the right thing because it is the right thing, is reason enough.  Trump and his friend Mark Burnett have ties to the Blagojevich family through a number of Celebrity reality television shows, including the Apprentice.  It could be that the president believes that there is a wrong being perpetrated on his friend, and that he can right that wrong.

Rod is a very charismatic fellow, and has a large base of very powerful and connected friends.  Having him owe you a favor, is something a political player could find very useful.  And let's face it Trump is willing to use gray colored morals when it comes to getting things done.  And Blago is very connected in the world on the gray moral politics.  I can see how Trump could leverage that power for himself to great advantage.

Comment: You might be able to turn this into a good answer, but as it is, it just seems too vague and generalized.

Answer (score -6):

I was wondering the same thing... Blago is a Democrat, and has absolutely zero political pull these days. Why would Trump pardon him?

Rod Blagojavich was a product of the Chicago Democratic machine, one of the most corrupt organizations in US government over the last hundred or so years. Even the [Chicago Tribune](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/columnists/kass/ct-chicago-aldermen-and-corruption-kass-1215-20161214-column.html) calls the city the 'corruption capital of the nation'. Someone else is also a product of that same machine... Barack Obama. You don't come through that machine without getting some manure on you.

It might well be that Blago has committed to release some incriminating or otherwise very embarrassing information on Obama in return for a get out of jail free card. Would certainly be in character for him to do something like that.

However, remember that Trump is only 'considering' a Blago pardon. This could be a veiled threat to the Dems... back off, or I'll turn your world upside down.

If in the coming months the Dems back down, and Blago doesn't get pardoned, that's probably what's going on. Or if Blago does get pardoned, and some nasty stuff comes out just before midterm elections...

This is probably not what the founding fathers had in mind when they came up with the presidential pardon.

However... remember that Bill Clinton pardoned incarcerated billionaire Marc Rich on Clinton's last day in office, and got some fat speaking fees from business associates of Rich not long after, plus a hefty donation to the Clinton presidential library, so a president using pardon powers for less than altruistic reasons is not without precedent.

Comment: Do you have any source for “information against Obama”, or is that pure speculation on your part?  Without *some* hint that he has such information, there’s no reason Democrats would see this as a threat.

Comment: *Blago is a Democrat, and has absolutely zero political pull these days* - You underestimate the power of the Chicago machine.

Comment: Everything in this answer appears to be conjecture based on wild speculations.